# sql query to return display by month

Tags: sql, pivot

I am trying to generate a query which returns results based on month.

For example:  table1

```
Name     Amount   createDate
p1        100      01/01/2012
p1         50      02/01/2012
p1        200      03/01/2012
p3        100      04/01/2012
```

The query should return:

```
Name Jan   Feb   Mar   April
p1   100   50    200    0
p2    0     0     0    100
```

Any suggestion or any idea of how to do it.

I am using db2 database.Sorry for missing the details

Comment: Take a look at what date functions are available in your DBMS.  Also, tell us what DBMS you are using so we can help more easily :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work...

```
select
  name, 
  case when month(createDate) = '1' then amount end as Jan,
  case when month(createDate) = '2' then amount end as Feb
  --etc...
from
  table1
group by
  name
;
```

However, the date equality test may not pass muster.  Like the others said, you'll probably have to look up date functions and find the one that suits your needs.

Comment: I used month(create_dtm) = '1' instead of CreateDate, it worked...Thanks

Comment: @Tim Pote, you cannot be specific for the dates like createDate = '20120101'....moreover, if CreateDate = '01/Jan/2012' and  CreateDate = '02/Jan/2012' for name='P1' then your entire solution will be wrong

Comment: Because I didn't know what database implementation he was using, i was going off of what I knew my regular database (PostGreSQL) could handle.  It makes that case from string to date automatically so that's perfectly normal for me.  But if you like, I'll alter it to use the month method that the OP used.

Comment: @anilpurswani Also, I specifically said at the end of the post that the date comparison probably wouldn't do exactly what he wanted.

"The date equality test may not pass muster. Like the others said, you'll probably have to look up date functions and find the one that suits your needs."